# Why does this strcpy code on a 2D array generate the wrong output?

Tags: c

I tried running this code of two dimensional charracter arrays (Arrays of strings)
Depending on the compiler and website the code showed garbage values at around 10x25-10x40 (string size).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    int n=0;
    char name[10][30];
    char e[20];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        strcpy(name[i],"0");
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        printf("\n%s",name[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is likely not a problem with a limit in the C compiler, but either in your code or of other external factors (like exhausting stack-space or similar). It's really impossible to tell without a proper [mre]. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Please format and indent your code before posting it here.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you go out of bounds of your array:

```
char name[10][30];
int i;
for( i=0;i<30;i++)
{
    strcpy(name[i],"0");
}
```

Here you iterate 30 times over an array of only 10 elements.

Comment: Yes. Note that in `char name[10][30];`, 10 is the number of strings and 30 is the length of each string.